# Go hitting max threads for process?

Tags: go

I'm trying out Go for doing some filesystem use analysis and I went for making the code as fast as possible by spawning almost everything off as a goroutine and relying on the Go VM (and GOMAXPROCS) to manage it.  I was watching this code run (pretty quickly) until it just stopped dead.  I checked top and it listed my process as having 1500 threads.

I thought maybe I had hit some limit and the process was therefore deadlocked waiting on the OS.  I checked my OS (FreeBSD) limits, and sure enough it was listed as 1500 threads max per process.

Surprised, I checked the Go docs and it says GOMAXPROCS is only a limit on running threads, but blocked threads don't count.

So my questions:

- Is it fair to say I can't rely on the Go VM as a global pool to prevent hitting OS limits of these kinds?
- Is there an idiomatic way to handle this (be nice, it's only my second day using Go)?

  - In particular, I haven't found a great way other than sync to close a channel when I'm done using it.  Is there a better way?
  - I'd like to abstract away the boilerplate (parallel mapping with go routines and 
    closing channel when done), is there a type-safe way to do this without generics?

Here's my current code:

```
func AnalyzePaths(paths chan string) chan AnalyzedPath {
    analyzed := make(chan AnalyzedPath)
    go func() {
        group := sync.WaitGroup{}
        for path := range paths {
            group.Add(1)
            go func(path string) {
                defer group.Done()
                analyzed <- Analyze(path)
            }(path)
        }
        group.Wait()
        close(analyzed)
    }()
    return analyzed
}

func GetPaths(roots []string) chan string {
    globbed := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        group := sync.WaitGroup{}
        for _, root := range roots {
            group.Add(1)
            go func(root string) {
                defer group.Done()
                for _, path := range glob(root) {
                    globbed <- path
                }
            }(root)
        }
        group.Wait()
        close(globbed)
    }()
    return globbed
}

func main() {
    paths := GetPaths(patterns)
    for analyzed := range AnalyzePaths(paths) {
        fmt.Println(analyzed)
    }
}
```

Comment: Some remarks: a) There is no Go VM. There is a Go runtime but this is not a virtual machine or something close to it. b) No, Go is not a day care which prevents you abusing your hardware; actually Go is low level enough to use your hardware well (but allows to cross the border). c) You say "making the code as fast as possible by spawning almost everything off as a goroutine" which looks problematic to me: Of course you need at least n concurrent goroutines to keep your n processor(core)s running at full load, but beyond that number goroutines provide convenience, not speedup.

Comment: a) Let's not be pedantic, since in this question VM and runtime are interchangeable as there *is* something sitting between my code and the hardware, managing it for me.  b) now you're being condescending... this is the language being regularly hyped as awesome for concurrency, smart resource management isn't IMO an unreasonable expectation.  c) Duh, but I'm not asking why I'm not getting faster performance, I'm asking if I'm deadlocking by hitting some OS limit.

Comment: a) Is not pedantry: Nothing sits between your code and the hardware. OS and the runtime sit more to the side of your code, not between. b) and c) won't lead anywhere: You expect something from Go which is impossible to deliver in all cases.

Comment: @Volker, It is pedantry since exchanging VM for runtime makes no difference regarding my question.  Second, Go has a "scheduler" to manage its goroutines- to me that certainly does indicate that when it comes to goroutines the runtime isn't 'sitting to the side'.  It is not impossible to deliver.  The runtime could check to see if there are OS limits and avoid creating more threads... it could respect GOMAXPROCS as meaning live and blocked threads, or it could add a GOMAXTHREADS option.  If I am running into the problem I think I am, any of the above would be nice and not 'impossible'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About 2 months ago (or more) language developers spoke about intruding of thread count control (and some other limits). So we can expect to see it soon. Month or more ago I develop the issue and found on my linux machine that GOMAXPROCS doesn't exceeds value of 256. If I sent 300 or more to it, the result was always 256. But I found that goroutines are not a threads. Goroutines can live in one thread.

As for idiomatic syncing - I think there is no necessity to sync too much.
In my code I usually use idea that goroutines are communicating through channels only. And channels should be passed as parameters for goroutines.

```
func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan SomeType1)
    ch2 := make(chan SomeType2)
    go generator(ch1, ch2)
    go processor(ch1, ch2)
    // here main func becomes waiting until it capture 2 of ch2-finished-signals 
    <- ch2
    <- ch2
    // usually we don't need the exact values of ch2-signals,
    // so we assign it to nothing 
}

func generator(ch1 chan SomeType1, ch2 chan SomeType2) {
    for (YOUR_CONDITION){
        // generate something
        //....
        // send to channel
        ch1 <- someValueOfType1
    }
    ch1 <- magicStopValue
    ch2 <- weAreFinishedSignal1
}

func processor(ch1 chan SomeType1, ch2 chan SomeType2) {
    // "read" value from ch1 
    value := <-ch1
    for value != magicStopValue {
        // make some processing
        // ....
        //get next value from ch1 and replay processing
        value = <- ch1
    }
    // here we can send signal that goroutine2 is finished
    ch2 <- weAreFinishedSignal2
}
```

If goroutines are in one thread they are communicating faster. As for me the channel performance is far from good, but enough for many purposes.

Comment: hmm, but since my goroutines could be executing out of order I wasn't sure how to know when to generate the 'weAreFinishedSignal' without using sync.  If I understand correctly, your example doesn't explicitly parallelize processing, but one could spawn n processors to get parallelization?

Comment: hm. here 3 bracnhes of execution. main branch spawn generator-branch and processor-branch, and than becomes sleepy (waiting signals from <-ch2). Spawned routines start their work, and generator send data to processor through channel ch1. If any goroutine ends job then it send to ch2 signal about finishing.

Comment: What I was doing was trying to spawn a new goroutine for every path I wanted analyzed while this setup is processing them serially per processor... if I want more parallelization I need to spawn more processors... but at least it sets an explicit limit.